# Validate form when setState doesn't run immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I've creating form in React and I have a problem with validation.

When we click (example and demo below) `Submit Form` without filling the input fields, we should get an error. This works fine. However, at the same time we also get the success message, which means this condition `(!this.state.firstNameError && !this.state.lastNameError)` returns `true`, but it shouldn't. It works fine only on second click.

This happens because `setState` is not updating immediately I guess.

I'm looking for a good solution to this issue.

I can do validate and submit in one method, and set `success` to `true` on callback after error's `setState`. But I don't want to hold so much code in one method (my really form is much bigger). What would be a better solution?

A simple code example:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    firstName: "",
    firstNameError: false,
    lastName: "",
    lastNameError: false,
    success: false
  };

  inputHandler = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  validateForm = () => {
    this.setState({
      firstNameError: false,
      lastNameError: false,
      success: false
    });

    if (!this.state.firstName) this.setState({ firstNameError: true });

    if (!this.state.lastName) this.setState({ lastNameError: true });
  };

  formSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.validateForm();

    if (!this.state.firstNameError && !this.state.lastNameError) {
      this.setState({ success: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { firstNameError, lastNameError, success } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
          <div className="row">
            <label>First Name: </label>
            <input onChange={this.inputHandler} name="firstName" type="text" />
          </div>
          {firstNameError && <div className="error">Enter First Name</div>}
          <div className="row">
            <label>Last Name: </label>
            <input onChange={this.inputHandler} name="lastName" type="text" />
          </div>
          {lastNameError && <div className="error">Enter Last Name</div>}
          <div className="row">
            <button>Submit Form</button>
          </div>
          {success && <div className="success">Success</div>}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/30p90v6kp

Comment: You should call setState only once in the formSubmit handler. Currently you are calling it up to 4 times. The current state does not update until the Component re-renders. You need to consolidate the state and only call setState once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `validateForm`, figure out the valid state of each field, then use that to determine whether the form as a whole is valid or not and only call `setState` once.

```
validateForm = () => {
  const firstNameError = !this.state.firstName;
  const lastNameError = !this.state.lastName;

  this.setState({
    firstNameError,
    lastNameError,
    success: !lastNameError && !firstNameError,
  });
};

formSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.validateForm();
};
```

Note - depending on how complex this is and how your form is actually submitted, you may decide whether or not this needs to be two different functions or not.  If you're waiting for `this.state.success` to be true to submit your form, use the callback of `setState` to do so.

```
this.setState(validatedState, newState => if (this.newState.success) submit() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display success msg by verifying first name and last name values also is like `if(this.state.firstName !== "" && this.state.lastName !== "") {
      this.setState({ success: true });
    }`it may help you. I provided the link below please find here https://codesandbox.io/s/q3ykw7wl3j